# Is there any example of HttpSendHttpResponse usage of the HTTP_SEND_RESPONSE_FLAG_OPAQUE flag (needed for WebSocket support)?

Tags: c++, winapi, websocket, wininet, winhttp

I am using `HttpSendHttpResponse()` with the `HTTP_SEND_RESPONSE_FLAG_OPAQUE` flag, as proposed by Microsoft (only with 101 response status and response headers prepared using the `WebSocketBeginServerHandshake()` function), but I receive an
`ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` error.

Without this flag, I'm able to establish a WebSocket connection with my server from my browser, but as far as I know I will not be able to use this connection as a WebSocket because `HTTP.SYS` would try to interpret the connection traffic as HTTP-framed.

Could someone provide me with a link to a working example of `HttpSendHttpResponse()` usage of the `HTTP_SEND_RESPONSE_FLAG_OPAQUE` flag?

Comment: Asking for tutorials and off-site resources is off-topic for StackOverflow. Please show the code you are having trouble with. A simple web search for `HTTP_SEND_RESPONSE_FLAG_OPAQUE` shows many examples

Comment: I searched, but could not find. I would be very grateful if you give me a link to at least one such example.

Comment: @AndyX I have opened [an issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/feedback/issues/1274) about this you can follow on github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the document: [HttpSendHttpResponse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/http/nf-http-httpsendhttpresponse)

> HttpSendHttpResponse returns ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER for all other
>   HTTP response types if HTTP_SEND_RESPONSE_FLAG_OPAQUE flag is used.

So it is expected. Just ignore this error temporarily and you can check the receiver part to see if it can receive the correct data.

Comment: Thank you, Rita. You're right. Actually it's expected for all other than 101 statuses (based on the same document), but adding  HTTP_SEND_RESPONSE_FLAG_MORE_DATA flag helps to omit this error and looks right according to the fact that this connection is going to be used for the future traffic.

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to use HTTP_SEND_RESPONSE_FLAG_OPAQUE flag correctly: it has to be used in conjunction with HTTP_SEND_RESPONSE_FLAG_MORE_DATA flag. Unfortunately, Microsoft doesn't mention this nuance in their documentation.

Comment: Hi AndyX, thanks for sharing your solution. I'll report this internally as a document issue.